# Using Style tag effectively in WPF for different images

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I use Styles to define what happens when a user hovers over an image like this.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="c:\\2.bmp"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="C:\\1.bmp"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But, I guess for all the images that I include in my application, the same images defined in 'Value' attributes are used.  What If I need a different on-hover image for different Images without this custom overriding?

In this case, any ideas what I should use? Or what is the better way to handle hovering of images in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define several different styles and give them an `x:Key` value, rather than a `TargetType` value.  You can then simply set the `Style` attribute of your images to the `x:Key` of the appropriate style.

If you want to apply a single style to the majority of your Images, but you want to override it for just a few of them, then you can combine the two methods.  If you assign a style to a type of element (via the `TargetType` attribute), you can override this on specific elements by explicitly specifying their `Style` attribute.  Also, if you set `Style={x:Null}`, you can make an element revert to the default style.

Answer (score 1):

We should define a x-key value like Jon suggested!

```
<Style x:Key="Name_of_your_style"  TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
<Setter Property="Source" Value="c:\\2.bmp"/>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="C:\\1.bmp"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

and while using this snippet use something like

```
 <Image Style="{StaticResource Name_of_your_style}"  Name="I1" />
 <Image Name="I2" />
```

This will make the image I1(defined first)  to use the above template(on hover handled) while the other image remains as per your current template.

Comment: Just a note, if you're using `x:Key`, you don't need to use `TargetType`.  I'm not sure how they work together.  I do know that when you don't set TargetType, you need to specify the class where your properties are defined (for your Setters), like so: `Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="c:\\2.bmp" />`

Comment: Thanks Jon.That piece was helpful. For me, when I used the above code(using both x:Key and TargetType), it worked fine as I posted. And Can u suggest me a good place to learn and understand things like these (I mean XAML , Images and each properties..)

Comment: I would recommend checking out the MSDN articles on WPF/XAML.  They can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx